# java.io.FileNotFoundException:/BOOT-inf/classes!/templates/

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

i am useing springboot create a project ,it's no error run idea,but, run app.jar file ,it's run Exception like this

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [templates/] cannot be resol
ed to absolute file path because it does not reside in the file system: jar:fil
:/E:/projects/help/target/zhx-help-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/BOOT-INF/classes!/templa
es/
    at org.springframework.util.ResourceUtils.getFile(ResourceUtils.java:21
)
    at org.springframework.core.io.AbstractFileResolvingResource.getFile(Ab
tractFileResolvingResource.java:52)
    at org.springframework.ui.freemarker.FreeMarkerConfigurationFactory.get
emplateLoaderForPath(FreeMarkerConfigurationFactory.java:338)
    at org.springframework.ui.freemarker.FreeMarkerConfigurationFactory.cre
teConfiguration(FreeMarkerConfigurationFactory.java:290)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.freemarker.FreeMarkerConfigurer
   afterPropertiesSet(FreeMarkerConfigurer.java:116)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBea
Factory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1687)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBea
Factory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1624)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBea
Factory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBea
Factory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getO
ject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegist
y.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetB
an(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBea
(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory
```

springboot version :1.5.2

useing spring-data-jpa

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see you use freemarker. In spring boot you cannot use the normal `File` approach to get your templates because they are not accessible when you run an executable JAR (`File` cannot be loaded as a resource when inside the JAR)

Use the following approach to load your templates folder:

```
cfg.setTemplateLoader(new ClassTemplateLoader(getClass().getClassLoader(), "templates"));
```

Full example:

```
@Configuration
public class FreemarkerConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public freemarker.template.Configuration freemarkerConfig() throws IOException {
        freemarker.template.Configuration cfg = new freemarker.template.Configuration(freemarker.template.Configuration.VERSION_2_3_23);
        cfg.setTemplateLoader(new ClassTemplateLoader(getClass().getClassLoader(), "templates"));
        cfg.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
        cfg.setTemplateExceptionHandler(TemplateExceptionHandler.RETHROW_HANDLER);
        cfg.setLogTemplateExceptions(false);
        return cfg;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 4):

If you are using jersey with spring boot, Jersey doesn't work well with Spring Boot. The reason for this error is, jersey is not able to auto discover all the rest resources. To fix this, register all the resources explicitly, registering package doesn't work. Hope this issue will be fixed in future versions of jersey.

public class JerseyConfig extends ResourceConfig {

```
public JerseyConfig() {
    register(Resource1.class);
    register(Resource2.class);
    register(Resource3.class);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

FreeMarkerConfigurationFactory.class

```
protected TemplateLoader getTemplateLoaderForPath(String templateLoaderPath) {
    if(this.isPreferFileSystemAccess()) {
        try {
            Resource ex = this.getResourceLoader().getResource(templateLoaderPath);
            File file = ex.getFile();
            if(this.logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
                this.logger.debug("Template loader path [" + ex + "] resolved to file path [" + file.getAbsolutePath() + "]");
            }

            return new FileTemplateLoader(file);
        } catch (IOException var4) {
            if(this.logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
                this.logger.debug("Cannot resolve template loader path [" + templateLoaderPath + "] to [java.io.File]: using SpringTemplateLoader as fallback", var4);
            }

            return new SpringTemplateLoader(this.getResourceLoader(), templateLoaderPath);
        }
    } else {
        this.logger.debug("File system access not preferred: using SpringTemplateLoader");
        return new SpringTemplateLoader(this.getResourceLoader(), templateLoaderPath);
    }
}
```

so make log lever info

```
<logger name="org.springframework.web" level="INFO"/>
```